# JavaScript Quiz Validating with onClick Function?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, switch-statement

I am trying to create a JavaScript Quiz.
The function will check the user's input value.
If it is correct; it will change the question.

Exact Code See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltmjv488/)

There are probably many more efficient and conventional ways to achieve what I am trying to do. Current issue is the function runs from the top every time it runs(obviously)

```
function checkAnswer() {

  var question = document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML;

  var userAnswer = document.getElementById("answer").value;

  if (userAnswer === "New York City") {

    alert("correct!");
    question = "What is the best college football team?";

    if (userAnswer === "Alabama") {
      alert("Correct!");
      question = "Next question will go here and so on..."

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool! What is the problem?

Comment: Are there multiple questions on the page you need to validate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In no way would I suggest doing things this way, but here's how to get your jsfiddle to work:

```
function check() {
    var question = document.getElementById('question').innerHTML
    var userAnswer = document.getElementById("answer").value;

    //Makes answer lowercase
    userAnswer = userAnswer.toLowerCase();

    //question one
    if (question === "Write One, Two, Three..") {
        if (userAnswer === "one two three") {
            alert('correct');
        }
        else {
            alert('Sorry Wrong!');
        }

        //question two  
        document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = "Write 4, 5, 6";
    }
    else {
        if (userAnswer === "4 5 6") {
            alert("correct!");
        }
        else {
            alert('Sorry Wrong!');
        }   
    }
}
```

One simple way to do what you want is to put your questions in an array:

```
var QandA = [
    ["question1...", "answer1...."],
    ["question2...", "answer2...."],
    ["question3...", "answer3...."],
    ["question4...", "answer4...."]
];

function check()
{
    // No more questions?
    if (0 === QandA.length) return;

    // Check answer
    var userAnswer = document.getElementById("answer").value.toLowerCase();
    if (userAnswer === QandA[0][1]) {
        alert("Correct");
    }
    else {
        alert("Incorrect");
    }
    // Delete that question
    QandA.shift();
    // And move to next
    if (0 != QandA.length) {
        document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = QandA[0][0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. But, now I am curious. How would you approach this?

And, why is it that for the first question you grab "QandA [0] [1 ]" but for the second you call for the first item twice ( QandA [0] [0] )

Comment: The biggest problem you have is that the user can view the source of the webpage and see all the answers. I would probably use Ajax to get the questions and answers from a server.

Comment: `QandA` is a 2-dimensional array. So, `QandA[n][0]` is the question for any given `n` (index) and `QandA[n][1]` is the answer for any given `n`. An array of objects probably would have been better.

Comment: actually Johnny - I just figured it out. It is actually a quite genius solution if you really had to code it within one function like I did.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a number of questions that you need validating I would take the following approach. It allows you as many questions as you like without repeating code.

First, store your questions in an array:

```
var arr = ["one two three", "4 5 6"];
```

Set a counter to zero, and a total (to measure the user performance):

```
var count = 0;
var total = 0;
```

Cache the elements:

```
var questionEl = document.getElementById('question');
var userAnswerEl = document.getElementById("answer");
```

Separate out the code that writes the question into a new function. It writes the question based on the counter:

```
function writeQuestion() {
    if (count < arr.length) {
      questionEl.innerHTML = "Write " + arr[count];
    } else {
      alert('No more questions. You have scored ' + total);
    }
}

function check() {
    userAnswer = userAnswerEl.value.toLowerCase();   
    if (userAnswer === arr[count]) {
        alert('correct');
        count++;
        total++;
        writeQuestion();
    } else {
        alert('Sorry Wrong!');
        count++;
        writeQuestion();
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0rntyen2/10/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (userAnswer === "New York City") {

  alert("correct!");
  question = "What is the best college football team?";

  if (userAnswer === "Alabama") {
    alert("Correct!");
    question = "Next question will go here and so on..."

  }
}
```

This block only runs if `userAnswer` is `"New York City"`, but inside it, you test whether `userAnswer` is `"Alabama"` - that will never be true. You probably want to move the second `if` outside of the first `if` block.

You seem to be assigning to `question` but not using the value. If you think you are updating the question text by assigning a value to `question` that isn't going to work. I think you are trying to do this:

```
question = document.getElementById("ques");

// later on...
question.innerHTML = "this is another question";

// even later...
question.innerHTML = "and here is a new question";
```

That would update the page for you because `question` would point to a DOM node and you can set `.innerHTML` on that, but the way you wrote it, you're setting `question` to a string value initially, and then other string values later, but not using any of them in anyway.